Build error of "No matching constructor for initialization" when initialize share_ptr<T[]> from unique_ptr<T[]>
First, I read this answer to realize why we want to convert an unique_ptr to a shared_ptr sometimes. Then, I follow the instructions of the converting constructor on cppreference shared_ptr.

In C++11 and C++14 it is valid to construct a std::shared_ptr<T> from a std::unique_ptr<T[]>:

std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[1]);
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(std::move(arr));


Since the shared_ptr obtains its deleter (a std::default_delete<T[]> object) from the std::unique_ptr, the array will be correctly deallocated.
This is no longer allowed in C++17. Instead the array form std::shared_ptr<T[]> should be used.

So, I try it on Ubuntu and Windows, respectively. The following code can be built PASS on Ubuntu using g++ v11.4.0
g++ -std=c++17 ./test.cpp -o test_cpp

#include <memory>
 
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[1]);
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> ptr(std::move(arr));

    return 0;
}

On the other hand, it shows the following error messages on Windows 11 using llvm-mingw g++ v12.0.0, which can be downloaded from here:
.\test.cpp:6:28: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::shared_ptr<int []>'
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> ptr(std::move(arr));
                           ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2711:23: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'typename remove_reference<unique_ptr<int []> &>::type'
      (aka 'std::unique_ptr<int []>') to 'std::nullptr_t' (aka 'nullptr_t') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR shared_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT;
                      ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2725:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'typename remove_reference<unique_ptr<int []> &>::type'
      (aka 'std::unique_ptr<int []>') to 'const std::shared_ptr<int []>' for 1st argument
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
    ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2732:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'typename remove_reference<unique_ptr<int []> &>::type'
      (aka 'std::unique_ptr<int []>') to 'std::shared_ptr<int []>' for 1st argument
    shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
    ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2713:18: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '_Yp *' against 'typename remove_reference<unique_ptr<int []> &>::type'
      (aka 'std::unique_ptr<int []>')
        explicit shared_ptr(_Yp* __p,
                 ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2728:9: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'shared_ptr' against 'unique_ptr'
        shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Yp>& __r,
        ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2733:52: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'shared_ptr' against 'unique_ptr'
    template<class _Yp> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY  shared_ptr(shared_ptr<_Yp>&& __r,
                                                   ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2736:34: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'unique_ptr'
    template<class _Yp> explicit shared_ptr(const weak_ptr<_Yp>& __r,
                                 ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2744:9: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '!is_array<int []>::value' was not satisfied
      [with _Yp = int [], _Dp = std::default_delete<int []>]
        shared_ptr(unique_ptr<_Yp, _Dp>&&,
        ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2753:9: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_lvalue_reference<std::default_delete<int []>>::value' was not satisfied
      [with _Yp = int [], _Dp = std::default_delete<int []>]
        shared_ptr(unique_ptr<_Yp, _Dp>&&,
        ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2709:23: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR shared_ptr() _NOEXCEPT;
                      ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2721:26: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
    template <class _Dp> shared_ptr(nullptr_t __p, _Dp __d);
                         ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2723:51: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
    template<class _Yp> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Yp>& __r, element_type* __p) _NOEXCEPT;
                                                  ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2716:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
        shared_ptr(_Yp* __p, _Dp __d,
        ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2722:40: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
    template <class _Dp, class _Alloc> shared_ptr(nullptr_t __p, _Dp __d, _Alloc __a);
                                       ^
C:\local\llvm-mingw-20210423-msvcrt-x86_64\include\c++\v1\memory:2719:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires at least 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
        shared_ptr(_Yp* __p, _Dp __d, _Alloc __a,
        ^
1 error generated.

If I change the allocated resource from array of objects to object, then it works.
    std::unique_ptr<int> arr(new int{1});
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(std::move(arr));

So, my question is:

Is there anything wrong in my test code?
Why are the results different among these two environments?
How to make it work on Windows with llvm-mingw?


Works here.

@user12002570, thanks. I tried it using mingw gcc from 11.3.0 to 13.1.0 and mingw clang from 14.0.3 to 16.0.2 available on Compiler Explorer and all of them work. I'll try another version of llvm-mingw on windows later.

Hmm, if I use the latest llvm-mingw v18.1.8 available on here rather than v12.0.0, then it works.

I’m voting to close this question because commenters report the code in question does actually compile successfully.

If I use llvm-mingw v18.1.8 rather than v12.0.0, then it works.
